# Strictly decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k^2+1}$$

Define the sequence $b_n=\dfrac{2a_n}{n} - n$.

I need to show that the sequence $\langle b_n\rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

$\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k^2+1}$ > $a_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k^2}$

for any positive n

As the definition of the RHS series (lets call it $c_n$) suggests, it is equal to the sum of the positive integers up to n.
This sum is given by the formula:

$$c_n=(n/2)(n+1)$$

Plugging this into your original definition for $b_n$ yields: $n + 1 - n$ or simply $1$.

Also note that the sum for $a_n$ approaches $c_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity. Now, with each increase in n, the difference between the 2 series steadily decreases.

Proving that the difference steadily decreases (from one term to the next) proves that $b_n$ steadily decreases (and as it seems, approaches 1). It's up to you to prove this critical bit.

Good day! :)

Comment: Your notation is confusing; I would suggest $c_n$ for the new series you have defined.  Further, you have proved that $b_n$ is bounded below, which is not the question.

Comment: @vadim123 Thank you for the suggestion, I agree! However, I fail to understand, by demonstrating that the series asymptotes to a constant (1), with each term steadily getting closer (which I would say, one could prove with calculus), how have we not implied that each term of $b_n$ is smaller than the previous, i.e. the whole thing is steadily decreasing?

Comment: You have demonstrated none of those things; at best you have suggested a strategy.

Comment: @vadim123 of course, I am aware that nothing is demonstrated (I should make it more clear in the answer). Though, I think the suggested "strategy" should work ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Try to show $b_{n+1} - b_n < 0$:

$b_{n+1} - b_n = \left[\dfrac{2a_{n+1}}{n+1} - (n+1)\right] -  \left[\dfrac{2a_n}n - n\right]$

$ = \dfrac1{n(n+1)}\left[2n \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sqrt{k^2+1} - 2(n+1) \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k^2+1} - n(n+1)\right]$

$ = \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[2n \sqrt{(n+1)^2 + 1} - 2 \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k^2+1} - n(n+1)\right]\qquad\qquad\mbox{(1)}$

$ < \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[2n \sqrt{\left(n + 1 + \dfrac1{2n}\right)^2} - 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \left(k + \dfrac1{2k}\right) - n(n+1)\right]$

$ < \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[2n \left(n + 1 + \dfrac1{2n}\right) - n(n+1) - \ln(n+1) - n(n+1)\right]$ ... [Ref: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Integral_test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Integral_test) to show $\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac1k > \ln(n+1)$]

$ = \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[1 - \ln(n+1)\right]$

$ < 0$ for all $n \geq 2$.

For $n = 1$ case: calculate: $b_2 - b_1 = \sqrt5 - \sqrt2 - 1 < 0$.

Revised part to fix mistake GL5 found, following from (1):

$ < \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[2n \sqrt{\left(n + 1 + \dfrac1{2(n+1)}\right)^2} - 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \left(k + \dfrac1{2(k+1)}\right) - n(n+1)\right]$

$ < \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[2n \sqrt{\left(n + 1 + \dfrac1{2(n+1)}\right)^2} - n(n+1) -  \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \dfrac1{k} - n(n+1)\right]$

$ < \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[2n \left(n + 1 + \dfrac1{2(n+1)}\right) - n(n+1) - \ln(n+1) + 1 - \dfrac1{n+1} - n(n+1)\right]$

$ = \dfrac1{n(n+1)} \left[2 - \dfrac2{n+1} - \ln(n+1)\right]$

$ < 0$ for all $n \geq 4$.

Initial cases for $1 \leq n \leq 3$ to be done by individual calculation. Having 3 initial cases is inelegant. There might be a way to tighten up the inequalities to reduce it.

Mick

Comment: Hi Mick A. Thanks for you reply, which I edited to incorportate $\LaTeX$. There's one bit I'm not sure of. apparently you claimed that $-\sqrt{k^2+1} < -\left(k+\dfrac1{2k}\right)$ i.e. $\sqrt{k^2+1} > \left(k+\dfrac1{2k}\right)$. Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Hi GL5. Thanks for Texing it! Also for seeing that mistake. I think if you use 1/(2(k+1)) instead of 1/(2k) it should fix that. It means you have to prove more initial cases though (up to n = 8 or 9?) so not very satisfying. There might a be a better tweak than that. Mick

Comment: I just added a revised part to address the problem found by GL5.